# Hans Der Kwast - Derive Streams and Catchments Model (r.to.vector not outputting file)

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, pcraster

I'm using the model created below and following the steps from 17:00 onwards

https://youtu.be/ZC0skH4ifsI?list=PLeuKJkIxCDj2Gk0CkcJ-QeviE41aMZd-5&t=1021

I've followed the osgeo4 installation steps below and to my knowledge everything is setup correctly for processing.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pja_EX0tVZA

when trying to run the model however on first try i get the following pop up error:

```
*Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\grassprovider\Grass7Algorithm.py", line 432, in processAlgorithm
    getattr(self, fullName)(parameters, context, feedback)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\grassprovider\Grass7Algorithm.py", line 485, in processInputs
    self.loadRasterLayerFromParameter(
  File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\grassprovider\Grass7Algorithm.py", line 738, in loadRasterLayerFromParameter
    self.loadRasterLayer(name, layer, context, external, band)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\grassprovider\Grass7Algorithm.py", line 755, in loadRasterLayer
    self.setSessionProjectionFromLayer(layer, context)
  File "C:\OSGeo4W/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\grassprovider\Grass7Algorithm.py", line 1059, in setSessionProjectionFromLayer
    self.setSessionProjection(layer.crs(), context)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'crs'*
```

On the second attempt i receive the following: in the advanced log:

*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AssetMap xmlns="http://www.smpte-ra.org/schemas/429-9/2007/AM"><Id>urn:uuid:2ec42852-105c-4a43-a156-f56d98668867</Id><AnnotationText>Created by DCP-o-matic 2.10.2 a23d6161d9</AnnotationText><Creator>DCP-o-matic 2.10.2 a23d6161d9</Creator><VolumeCount>1</VolumeCount><IssueDate>2019-03-18T21:16:44+13:00</IssueDate><Issuer>DCP-o-matic 2.10.2 a23d6161d9</Issuer><AssetList><Asset><Id>urn:uuid:96155a97-29b5-4492-bd9d-fa7fef01e085</Id><PackingList>true</PackingList><ChunkList><Chunk><Path>pkl_96155a97-29b5-4492-bd9d-fa7fef01e085.xml</Path><VolumeIndex>1</VolumeIndex><Offset>0</Offset><Length>8125</Length></Chunk></ChunkList></Asset><Asset><Id>urn:uuid:12d6deb6-f57a-48d9-a04e-9f3d308769a7</Id><ChunkList><Chunk><Path>cpl_12d6deb6-f57a-48d9-a04e-9f3d308769a7.xml</Path><VolumeIndex>1</VolumeIndex><Offset>0</Offset><Length>8579</Length></Chunk></ChunkList></Asset><Asset><Id>urn:uuid:b423032b-2d73-443e-aa78-cf8ae272f678</Id><ChunkList><Chunk><Path>j2c_b423032b-2d73-443e-aa78-cf8ae272f678.mxf</Path><VolumeIndex>1</VolumeIndex><Offset>0</Offset><Length>34292022253</Length></Chunk></ChunkList></Asset><Asset><Id>urn:uuid:ab539980-1360-49a2-9a58-ac3ddb1ca264</Id><ChunkList><Chunk><Path>pcm_ab539980-1360-49a2-9a58-ac3ddb1ca264.mxf</Path><VolumeIndex>1</VolumeIndex><Offset>0</Offset><Length>2671321846</Length></Chunk></ChunkList></Asset></AssetList></AssetMap>
QGIS version: 3.34.1-Prizren
QGIS code revision: 133927424d
Qt version: 5.15.3
Python version: 3.9.5
GDAL version: 3.8.0
GEOS version: 3.12.1-CAPI-1.18.1
PROJ version: Rel. 9.3.0, September 1st, 2023
PDAL version: 2.6.0 (git-version: e4d82c)
Algorithm started at: 2023-12-01T12:48:12
Algorithm 'Stream and Catchment Delineation' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'opentopography_api_key' : 'x', 'original_outlet' : 'C:/QGIS/OOutlet.shp', 'output_catchment_polygon' : 'C:/QGIS/Catchment.shp', 'output_crs' : QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:3857'), 'output_dem' : 'C:/QGIS/DEM.map', 'output_streams' : 'C:/QGIS/Streams.shp', 'select_outlet_point_on_map' : '-350348.154673,6941233.256242 [EPSG:3857]', 'snapped_outlet' : 'C:/QGIS/SOutlet.shp', 'strahler_order_threshold' : 1, 'study_area_extent' : '-413495.942200000,-279473.181300000,6892863.139300000,6994510.631400000 [EPSG:3857]' }
208 KB downloaded
631 KB downloaded
1.12 MB downloaded
1.75 MB downloaded
2.34 MB downloaded
2.86 MB downloaded
3.40 MB downloaded
4.28 MB downloaded
5.20 MB downloaded
5.99 MB downloaded
Successfully downloaded https://portal.opentopography.org/API/globaldem?demtype=SRTMGL1&south=52.50995945846993&north=53.06219512410649&west=-3.714497247996622&east=-2.510550302632965&outputFormat=GTiff&API_Key=x
Results: {'OUTPUT': 'C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/c1172d8d912c4f7e922857bbb795aa5b/OUTPUT.tif'}
Results: {'OUTPUT': 'OUTPUT_f3c14430_73b5_46ef_a91f_06bd962b775d'}
GDAL command:
gdalwarp -overwrite -t_srs EPSG:3857 -dstnodata -9999.0 -tr 30.0 30.0 -r near -of GTiff C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/c1172d8d912c4f7e922857bbb795aa5b/OUTPUT.tif C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/41d12508512d42b1aa99b7949ac749f9/OUTPUT.tif
GDAL command output:
Creating output file that is 4467P x 3388L. 
Processing C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/c1172d8d912c4f7e922857bbb795aa5b/OUTPUT.tif [1/1] : 0Using internal nodata values (e.g. -32768) for image C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/c1172d8d912c4f7e922857bbb795aa5b/OUTPUT.tif. 
...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
Process completed successfully
g.proj -c wkt="C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/5e2e5696bb93415997ef530524217948/crs.prj"
r.external input="C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_BnbpXZ\9223d564a64c4a778ae4530858eb075d\OUTPUT.map" band=1 output="rast_65692082d45912" --overwrite -o
g.region n=6994541.3788727475 s=6892901.3788727475 e=-279495.52517324715 w=-413505.52517324715 res=30.0
r.thin input=rast_65692082d45912 iterations=200 output=output96f29303dc1a4c949217976b1bb8244d --overwrite
g.region raster=output96f29303dc1a4c949217976b1bb8244d
r.out.gdal -t -m input="output96f29303dc1a4c949217976b1bb8244d" output="C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_BnbpXZ\7db1f961b8f1469c8f3155b23acc9173\output.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows
C:\Users\x\Documents>chcp 1252 1>NUL
C:\Users\x\Documents>g.proj -c wkt="C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/5e2e5696bb93415997ef530524217948/crs.prj"
C:\Users\x\Documents>r.external input="C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_BnbpXZ\9223d564a64c4a778ae4530858eb075d\OUTPUT.map" band=1 output="rast_65692082d45912" --overwrite -o
C:\Users\x\Documents>g.region n=6994541.3788727475 s=6892901.3788727475 e=-279495.52517324715 w=-413505.52517324715 res=30.0
C:\Users\x\Documents>r.thin input=rast_65692082d45912 iterations=200 output=output96f29303dc1a4c949217976b1bb8244d --overwrite
C:\Users\x\Documents>g.region raster=output96f29303dc1a4c949217976b1bb8244d
C:\Users\x\Documents>r.out.gdal -t -m input="output96f29303dc1a4c949217976b1bb8244d" output="C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_BnbpXZ\7db1f961b8f1469c8f3155b23acc9173\output.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
C:\Users\x\Documents>exit
Error encountered while running Assign projection: Could not load source layer for INPUT: invalid value
Execution failed after 396.85 seconds (6 minutes 37 seconds)
Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Stream and Catchment Delineation' finished
QGIS version: 3.34.1-Prizren
QGIS code revision: 133927424d
Qt version: 5.15.3
Python version: 3.9.5
GDAL version: 3.8.0
GEOS version: 3.12.1-CAPI-1.18.1
PROJ version: Rel. 9.3.0, September 1st, 2023
PDAL version: 2.6.0 (git-version: e4d82c)
Algorithm started at: 2023-12-01T12:55:12
Algorithm 'Stream and Catchment Delineation' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'opentopography_api_key' : 'x', 'original_outlet' : 'C:/QGIS/OOutlet.shp', 'output_catchment_polygon' : 'C:/QGIS/Catchment.shp', 'output_crs' : QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:3857'), 'output_dem' : 'C:/QGIS/DEM.map', 'output_streams' : 'C:/QGIS/Streams.shp', 'select_outlet_point_on_map' : '-350348.154673,6941233.256242 [EPSG:3857]', 'snapped_outlet' : 'C:/QGIS/SOutlet.shp', 'strahler_order_threshold' : 1, 'study_area_extent' : '-413495.942200000,-279473.181300000,6892863.139300000,6994510.631400000 [EPSG:3857]' }
Prepare algorithm: native:pointtolayer_1
Running Create layer from point [1/21]
Input Parameters:
{ INPUT: '-350348.154673,6941233.256242 [EPSG:3857]', OUTPUT: 'memory:Point' }
Results:
{ OUTPUT: 'Point_12a7dcba_b6d1_485b_96a3_7ef725288079' }
OK. Execution took 0.019 s (1 output(s)).
Prepare algorithm: OTDEMDownloader:OpenTopography DEM Downloader_1
Running OpenTopography DEM Downloader [2/21]
Input Parameters:
{ API_key: 'x', DEMs: 1, Extent: '-413495.942200000,-279473.181300000,6892863.139300000,6994510.631400000 [EPSG:3857]', OUTPUT: 'C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/87ba585e0e3a4e2a894471c4844e3a58/OUTPUT.tif' }
16 KB downloaded
72 KB downloaded
312 KB downloaded
591 KB downloaded
855 KB downloaded
1.10 MB downloaded
1.43 MB downloaded
1.65 MB downloaded
1.87 MB downloaded
2.06 MB downloaded
2.51 MB downloaded
3.26 MB downloaded
3.91 MB downloaded
4.57 MB downloaded
4.82 MB downloaded
5.73 MB downloaded
6.35 MB downloaded
Successfully downloaded https://portal.opentopography.org/API/globaldem?demtype=SRTMGL1&south=52.50995945846993&north=53.06219512410649&west=-3.714497247996622&east=-2.510550302632965&outputFormat=GTiff&API_Key=x
Results: {'OUTPUT': 'C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/87ba585e0e3a4e2a894471c4844e3a58/OUTPUT.tif'}
Results: {'OUTPUT': 'OUTPUT_a3df48a9_84eb_4d65_9516_9cfaa1791c6a'}
Results:
{ OUTPUT: 'C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/87ba585e0e3a4e2a894471c4844e3a58/OUTPUT.tif' }
OK. Execution took 28.536 s (1 output(s)).
Prepare algorithm: native:reprojectlayer_1
Running Reproject layer [3/21]
Input Parameters:
{ INPUT: 'memory://Point?crs=EPSG:3857&field=id:integer(0,0)&uid={5ed37926-f311-4bc8-8de3-12b327ef29a1}', OPERATION: '', OUTPUT: 'C:/QGIS/OOutlet.shp', TARGET_CRS: QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:3857') }
Results:
{ OUTPUT: 'C:/QGIS/OOutlet.shp' }
OK. Execution took 0.011 s (1 output(s)).
Prepare algorithm: gdal:warpreproject_1
Running Warp (reproject) [4/21]
Input Parameters:
{ DATA_TYPE: 0, EXTRA: '', INPUT: 'C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/87ba585e0e3a4e2a894471c4844e3a58/OUTPUT.tif', MULTITHREADING: False, NODATA: -9999, OPTIONS: '', OUTPUT: 'C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/4e4ca54069774e1d8192de912d697a94/OUTPUT.tif', RESAMPLING: 0, SOURCE_CRS: None, TARGET_CRS: QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:3857'), TARGET_EXTENT: None, TARGET_EXTENT_CRS: None, TARGET_RESOLUTION: 30 }
GDAL command:
gdalwarp -overwrite -t_srs EPSG:3857 -dstnodata -9999.0 -tr 30.0 30.0 -r near -of GTiff C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/87ba585e0e3a4e2a894471c4844e3a58/OUTPUT.tif C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/4e4ca54069774e1d8192de912d697a94/OUTPUT.tif
GDAL command output:
Creating output file that is 4467P x 3388L. 
Processing C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/87ba585e0e3a4e2a894471c4844e3a58/OUTPUT.tif [1/1] : 0Using internal nodata values (e.g. -32768) for image C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/87ba585e0e3a4e2a894471c4844e3a58/OUTPUT.tif. 
...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
Process completed successfully
Results:
{ OUTPUT: 'C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/4e4ca54069774e1d8192de912d697a94/OUTPUT.tif' }
OK. Execution took 0.44 s (1 output(s)).
Prepare algorithm: pcraster:converttopcrasterformat_1
Running Convert DEM to PCRaster Format [5/21]
Input Parameters:
{ INPUT: 'C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/4e4ca54069774e1d8192de912d697a94/OUTPUT.tif', INPUT2: 3, OUTPUT: 'C:/QGIS/DEM.map' }
Results:
{ OUTPUT: 'C:/QGIS/DEM.map' }
OK. Execution took 0.142 s (1 output(s)).
Prepare algorithm: pcraster:lddcreate_1
Running Calculate flow direction [6/21]
Input Parameters:
{ INPUT: 'C:/QGIS/DEM.map', INPUT0: 0, INPUT1: 0, INPUT2: 9999999, INPUT3: 9999999, INPUT4: 9999999, INPUT5: 9999999, OUTPUT: 'C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/eee9529402d249438443d5a23b88c370/OUTPUT.map' }
Results:
{ OUTPUT: 'C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/eee9529402d249438443d5a23b88c370/OUTPUT.map' }
OK. Execution took 189.195 s (1 output(s)).
Prepare algorithm: pcraster:spatial_1
Running Create Strahler order threshold raster [7/21]
Input Parameters:
{ INPUT: 1, INPUT1: 2, INPUT2: 'C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/eee9529402d249438443d5a23b88c370/OUTPUT.map', OUTPUT: 'C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/c9544f6bc05f4b0582009a18ef5ecb75/OUTPUT.map' }
Results:
{ OUTPUT: 'C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/c9544f6bc05f4b0582009a18ef5ecb75/OUTPUT.map' }
OK. Execution took 0.093 s (1 output(s)).
Prepare algorithm: pcraster:streamorder_1
Running Calculate Strahler orders [8/21]
Input Parameters:
{ INPUT: 'C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/eee9529402d249438443d5a23b88c370/OUTPUT.map', OUTPUT: 'C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/e8e0b6befb46498094e99a15372d0df8/OUTPUT.map' }
Results:
{ OUTPUT: 'C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/e8e0b6befb46498094e99a15372d0df8/OUTPUT.map' }
OK. Execution took 3.869 s (1 output(s)).
Prepare algorithm: pcraster:comparisonoperators_1
Running Select Strahler orders >= threshold [9/21]
Input Parameters:
{ INPUT: 'C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/e8e0b6befb46498094e99a15372d0df8/OUTPUT.map', INPUT1: 1, INPUT2: 'C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/c9544f6bc05f4b0582009a18ef5ecb75/OUTPUT.map', OUTPUT: 'C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/f5aab5620db445d2a1908603e8245899/OUTPUT.map' }
Results:
{ OUTPUT: 'C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/f5aab5620db445d2a1908603e8245899/OUTPUT.map' }
OK. Execution took 0.162 s (1 output(s)).
Prepare algorithm: pcraster:ifthen_1
Running Assign Strahler orders to river [10/21]
Input Parameters:
{ INPUT: 'C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/f5aab5620db445d2a1908603e8245899/OUTPUT.map', INPUT1: 'C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/e8e0b6befb46498094e99a15372d0df8/OUTPUT.map', OUTPUT: 'C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/57eb9282a3b04b1e91db332c7886a98d/OUTPUT.map' }
Results:
{ OUTPUT: 'C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/57eb9282a3b04b1e91db332c7886a98d/OUTPUT.map' }
OK. Execution took 0.151 s (1 output(s)).
Prepare algorithm: grass7:r.thin_1
Running Thin river raster [11/21]
Input Parameters:
{ GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META: '', GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT: '', GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER: 0, GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER: None, input: 'C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/57eb9282a3b04b1e91db332c7886a98d/OUTPUT.map', iterations: 200, output: 'C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/594c79871a75451193cf525ffc0a4560/output.tif' }
Algorithm “r.thin” cannot be run in a background thread, switching to main thread for this step
g.proj -c wkt="C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/3acfbe6c05ac458399c130840d4f85b9/crs.prj"
r.external input="C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_BnbpXZ\57eb9282a3b04b1e91db332c7886a98d\OUTPUT.map" band=1 output="rast_6569222f9ad943" --overwrite -o
g.region n=6994541.3788727475 s=6892901.3788727475 e=-279495.52517324715 w=-413505.52517324715 res=30.0
r.thin input=rast_6569222f9ad943 iterations=200 output=outputcc9c48c7c6804438a4eaf209cb81a83d --overwrite
g.region raster=outputcc9c48c7c6804438a4eaf209cb81a83d
r.out.gdal -t -m input="outputcc9c48c7c6804438a4eaf209cb81a83d" output="C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_BnbpXZ\594c79871a75451193cf525ffc0a4560\output.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows
C:\Users\x\Documents>chcp 1252 1>NUL
C:\Users\x\Documents>g.proj -c wkt="C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/3acfbe6c05ac458399c130840d4f85b9/crs.prj"
C:\Users\x\Documents>r.external input="C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_BnbpXZ\57eb9282a3b04b1e91db332c7886a98d\OUTPUT.map" band=1 output="rast_6569222f9ad943" --overwrite -o
C:\Users\x\Documents>g.region n=6994541.3788727475 s=6892901.3788727475 e=-279495.52517324715 w=-413505.52517324715 res=30.0
C:\Users\x\Documents>r.thin input=rast_6569222f9ad943 iterations=200 output=outputcc9c48c7c6804438a4eaf209cb81a83d --overwrite
C:\Users\x\Documents>g.region raster=outputcc9c48c7c6804438a4eaf209cb81a83d
C:\Users\x\Documents>r.out.gdal -t -m input="outputcc9c48c7c6804438a4eaf209cb81a83d" output="C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_BnbpXZ\594c79871a75451193cf525ffc0a4560\output.tif" format="GTiff" createopt="TFW=YES,COMPRESS=LZW" --overwrite
C:\Users\x\Documents>exit
Results:
{ output: 'C:\\Users\\x\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\processing_BnbpXZ\\594c79871a75451193cf525ffc0a4560\\output.tif' }
OK. Execution took 0.569 s (1 output(s)).
Prepare algorithm: grass7:r.to.vect_1
Running Convert river raster to line vector [12/21]
Input Parameters:
{ -b: False, -s: False, -t: False, -v: True, -z: False, GRASS_OUTPUT_TYPE_PARAMETER: 0, GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER: 0, GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER: None, GRASS_VECTOR_DSCO: '', GRASS_VECTOR_EXPORT_NOCAT: False, GRASS_VECTOR_LCO: '', column: 'value', input: 'C:\\Users\\x\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\processing_BnbpXZ\\594c79871a75451193cf525ffc0a4560\\output.tif', output: 'C:/Users/x/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_BnbpXZ/e21e1daf000f4465b1ac28eac97c5647/output.gpkg', type: 0 }
Algorithm “r.to.vect” cannot be run in a background thread, switching to main thread for this step
g.region n=-1.7976931348623157e+308 s=1.7976931348623157e+308 e=-1.7976931348623157e+308 w=1.7976931348623157e+308 res=100.0
r.to.vect input=rast_6569222f9ad943 type="line" column="value" -v output=output658f7236920f4010acfcaa3dca9ef39b --overwrite
v.out.ogr type="auto" input="output658f7236920f4010acfcaa3dca9ef39b" output="C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_BnbpXZ\e21e1daf000f4465b1ac28eac97c5647\output.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows
C:\Users\x\Documents>chcp 1252 1>NUL
C:\Users\x\Documents>g.region n=-1.7976931348623157e+308 s=1.7976931348623157e+308 e=-1.7976931348623157e+308 w=1.7976931348623157e+308 res=100.0
C:\Users\x\Documents>r.to.vect input=rast_6569222f9ad943 type="line" column="value" -v output=output658f7236920f4010acfcaa3dca9ef39b --overwrite
C:\Users\x\Documents>v.out.ogr type="auto" input="output658f7236920f4010acfcaa3dca9ef39b" output="C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_BnbpXZ\e21e1daf000f4465b1ac28eac97c5647\output.gpkg" format="GPKG" --overwrite
C:\Users\x\Documents>exit
Results:
{ output: 'C:\\Users\\x\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\processing_BnbpXZ\\e21e1daf000f4465b1ac28eac97c5647\\output.gpkg' }
OK. Execution took 0.557 s (1 output(s)).
Prepare algorithm: native:assignprojection_1
Running Assign projection [13/21]
Input Parameters:
{ CRS: QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:3857'), INPUT: 'C:\\Users\\x\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\processing_BnbpXZ\\e21e1daf000f4465b1ac28eac97c5647\\output.gpkg', OUTPUT: 'memory:Assigned CRS' }
Error encountered while running Assign projection: Could not load source layer for INPUT: C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Temp\processing_BnbpXZ\e21e1daf000f4465b1ac28eac97c5647\output.gpkg not found
Execution failed after 336.74 seconds (5 minutes 37 seconds)
Loading resulting layers
Algorithm 'Stream and Catchment Delineation' finished
```

- 

It looks to me like the grass v.to.vector algorithm is failing to create the output which is killing the whole model. beyond this I'm a bit lost!

I note the two following warnings:

WARNING: Concurrent mapset locking is not supported on Windows

Algorithm “r.thin” cannot be run in a background thread, switching to main thread for this step

But both seem explainable with a quick Google.

As mentioned as far as I can tell everything is set up as it should be. The grass plugin is activated. I note from the QGIS knowledge base that Windows users should be opening QGIS Desktop with GRASS. but i think this is old information?

I've tried different output locations to mitigate permission issues, ive installed all versions of GRASS, ive tried the ltr and the beta of QGIS.

Comment: r.to vector fails because g.region fails to create a valid region, inside Convert river raster to line vector [12/21] step. Why does it fail? We don't know, but the region parameter as None and cell size as 0 are strange. Check if you can explicitly define the region and cell size for this process in the algorithm dialog, maybe in advanced parameters.

Comment: Hi Gabriel, Thank you 

The region should be pulled from the extent definition parameter input.

When looking at [11] & [12] both have region parameter as None and cell size as 0 it seems they are pulling the date for gregion from the input

n=6994541.3788727475 s=6892901.3788727475 e=-279495.52517324715 w=-413505.52517324715 res=30.0

if manually editing in the advanced section would the formatting be:

GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER: 30.0, GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER: n=6994541 s=6892901 e=-279495 w=-41350

Thanks!

Comment: So I fixed this by downgrading grass 7.84 to 7.83 through osgeo4. after this I had a new error that told me r.thin was timing out after 200 iterations. I upped this to 2000 and now its fixed! i now have a new error but am going to try to figure that out by myself before posting again :) thanks!